# Clicking a Link on a Web page by using Keywords

Tags: c#, html

I want to be able to open supreme's website, (www.supremenewyork.com), go to any of the tabs (shirts, jackets, etc.) and be able to input the **keywords** of the shirt I want to click on, and then have my program click on it.

I figured out how to get it to automatically click onto checkout and fill out the fields. Here is the html for a random shirt that we will use for example.

https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/shirts

I want to click on the `Houndstooth Flannel Zip Up Shirt` in the color Red

I have read that you need to use `HTMLAgilityPack` to be able to type in those `inner text's` for the keywords. But I think you guys can send me the right way.

**Here is the HTML**

```
<article><div class="inner-article"><a style="height:150px;" href="/shop/shirts/gsfge9btl/mkza7miyc"><img width="150" height="150" src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/160974/vi/eYFAEBVxJT0.jpg" alt="Eyfaebvxjt0"></a><h1><a class="name-link" href="/shop/shirts/gsfge9btl/mkza7miyc">Houndstooth Flannel Zip Up Shirt</a></h1><p><a class="name-link" href="/shop/shirts/gsfge9btl/mkza7miyc">Red</a></p></div></article>
```

Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace Supreme
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://supremenewyork.com/shop");

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/accessories");

    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (HtmlElement btn in 
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
        {
            if (btn.GetAttribute("className") == "button")
            {
                btn.InvokeMember("Click");
            }
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://supremenewyork.com/shop/all/shirts");


    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.GoBack();
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (HtmlElement btn in
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a"))
            {
                if (btn.GetAttribute("className") == "button checkout")
                {
                    btn.InvokeMember("Click");
                }
            }
    }
}
```

THANK YOU!

Comment: There is a lot of unnecessary information in this post. *What* is your question? Does the code you provided function/work? If not, what about it is not working? Are you getting an error? Where? In this case- we need to know more about the code

Comment: Sorry. I'm trying to use examples and such to help understand. I want to automate a click on a link on a website by finding it by keywords I manually put in. My code works perfectly fine. I just don't know to search for specific keywords in htmls and that is what I was asking about.